# htaccess to fix broken links on local site

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, hyperlink

So after moving a live site onto a local computer for offline show casing, a lot of the links have broken because of missplaced `../` that dreamweaver puts in.

It works online because the user of that domain doesn't have permission to leave it's doc root, but not so locally.

Is there an .htaccess that I could put the root dir that would restrict or redirect back to itself when trying to navigate to it's parent?

So the site is in `xampp/mysite/` and an img src has a value of `../images/image.png`

So it's looking for the image at `xampp/images/image.png` instead of staying in it's root dir of `xampp/mysite/images/image.png`

Comment: So a request from `tld/parent-dir/sub-dir/index.php` has a reference to image that resolves to `tld/parent-dir/image.php` and you want it to serve an image from `tld/parent-dir/sub-dir/image.php`?  If not, can you provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that all of your images are in the `/xampp/mysite/images` directory.

If so, then you could try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if request is not in xampp/mysite/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xampp/mysite/images/ [NC]
#rewrite images to /xampp/mysite/images
RewriteRule /(.+\\.(png|jpg|gif))$ /xampp/mysite/images/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Images are just an example. It's also happening with links, ie a `<a href="../index.php">` would go to `xampp/index.php` not `xampp/mysite/index.php`